# Unable to submit queries using mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

i am new here and this is my first question here!
I am having difficulties in mysql and php

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
$con=mysql_connect('localhost:3306','dmail','*****','dhruv');    
if(!$con)
{
echo "Failed to connect"; }

$name2 = 'name2';
$tel_no2 = 'tel_no2';
$email2 = 'email2';
$query2 = 'query2';
$car = 'car';
$city2 = 'city2';
$country2 = 'country2';
$date = 'date';

$query1 ="INSERT INTO 'booking' VALUES (name2, tel_no2, email2, city2, country2, car,         date, query2)";
$query2 ="INSERT INTO 'booking' VALUES ('$name2', '$tel_no2', '$email2', '$city2',     '$country2', '$car', '$date', '$query2')"; 

$update = mysql_query($query1,$con);
if(!$update)
{    echo "Failed to update"; }

>
```

It always shows me "Failed to update", any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you dont need the `$con` in `mysql_query($query1, $con);`

Comment: In case of a mysql error, use `echo mysql_error()`!

Comment: @Þaw You don't *need* it, but it is **very good practice** to explicitly pass it!

Comment: his `$query1`  also contains syntax errors

Comment: The `mysql` library is deprecated and you should be using either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: You have several errors all throughout your script. They will all manifest as error when executing the query. Get used to the pattern `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` now, otherwise you're never going to find them all.

Comment: Try your queries in MySQL before you use them in code. Or at least use `mysql_error()` in PHP like deceze suggested!

Comment: Hey, thanks guys for your support. It really did helped!
But in my database its passing directly the variable name not the variable's value.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost:3306','dmail','*****','dhruv');
```

should be

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost:3306','dmail','*****'); 
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dhruv', $con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'` around table_name and add `'` and `$` around values

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO `booking` VALUES ('$name2', '$tel_no2', '$email2', '$city2', '$country2', '$car','$date', '$query2')";
$query2 ="INSERT INTO `booking` VALUES ('$name2', '$tel_no2', '$email2', '$city2',     '$country2', '$car', '$date', '$query2')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$` in mysql queries to actually insert the values to the table. So :

```
//This query is not valid since you are neither passing a string nor a variable
$query1 ="INSERT INTO 'booking' VALUES (name2, tel_no2, email2, city2, country2, car,         date, query2)";
```

So this should be either enclosed in single quotations like this (to literally pass `name2`, `tel_no2`, etc):

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO 'booking' VALUES ('name2', 'tel_no2', 'email2', 'city2', 'country2', 'car', 'date', 'query2')";
```

Or you can pass the values of the variables like this:

```
$query2 ="INSERT INTO 'booking' VALUES ('$name2', '$tel_no2', '$email2', '$city2',     '$country2', '$car', '$date', '$query2')";
```